# Trouble in SQL Summing a Word

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to `Sum()` the column `Status` where `Status = 'operational'`. I am having trouble figuring out how to sum the actual word "operational".

I have tried multiple different variations of the statement below (the one I posted is the most basic form) but I get the error: `data type varchar is invalid for sum operator`.

Can anybody help?

```
SELECT SUM(status) As 'TotalOperationalSTIDevices'
FROM netinfo_device_details
WHERE LoopBackAddress LIKE '10.12%' AND Status = 'Operational'
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? Can you please choose one tag or the other?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As TotalOperationalSTIDevices 
FROM netinfo_device_details 
WHERE LoopBackAddress LIKE '10.12%' AND Status = 'Operational';
```

The SUM aggregation function really does a SUM of a set of numbers. COUNT just counts the number of rows.
Since the actual content of the row is not relevant, you can use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(status) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select COUNT(*) As 'TotalOperationalSTIDevices' from netinfo_device_details where LoopBackAddress Like '10.12%' and Status = 'Operational'
```